# Redis Object storage and conversion

Tags: c#, reflection, redis

I am stepping into a new realm with this project, **Reflection**. I have written some working code (below) that will potentially store POCO objects in a redis cache (and eventually backed by Table or other nosql persistant storage).

Currently it only reads the objects from the cache, but after this review I will be attempting to reverse the process and store the POCOs in the cache.

I am posting this due to my weakness with Reflection, but feel free to correct me on any other issues.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Demgel.Redis.Attributes;
using StackExchange.Redis;

namespace Demgel.Redis
{
    public static class DemgelRedis
    {
        public static IEnumerable<HashEntry> ConvertToRedisHash(object o, bool ignoreFail = false)
        {
            var hashList = new List<HashEntry>();
            foreach (var prop in o.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                var type = prop.PropertyType;
                if (type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof (Guid)))
                {
                    var guid = prop.GetValue(o, null) as Guid?;
                    if (guid.HasValue)
                    {
                        hashList.Add(new HashEntry(prop.Name, guid.Value.ToString()));
                    }
                }
                else if (type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(string)))
                {
                    var value = prop.GetValue(o, null) as string;
                    if (value != null)
                    {
                        hashList.Add(new HashEntry(prop.Name, value));
                    }
                }

            }
            return hashList;
        }

        public static object ConvertToObject(object obj, HashEntry[] hashEntries, bool ignoreFail = false)
        {
            var hashDict = hashEntries.ToDictionary();

            foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                RedisValue hashPair;
                if (!hashDict.TryGetValue(prop.Name, out hashPair)) continue;

                var type = prop.PropertyType;
                if (type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Guid)))
                {
                    Guid value;
                    if (!Guid.TryParse(hashPair, out value))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            value = new Guid((byte[]) hashPair);
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            value = Guid.Empty;
                        }
                    }
                    prop.SetValue(obj, value);
                }
                else if (type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(string)))
                {
                    prop.SetValue(obj, (string)hashPair);
                }
                else if (type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(float)))
                {
                    prop.SetValue(obj, (float)Convert.ToDouble(hashPair));
                }
                else if (type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(double)))
                {
                    prop.SetValue(obj, Convert.ToDouble(hashPair));
                }
                else if (type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(int)))
                {
                    prop.SetValue(obj, int.Parse(hashPair));
                }
                else if (type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof (DateTime)))
                {
                    DateTime dateTime;
                    if (DateTime.TryParse(hashPair, out dateTime))
                    {
                        prop.SetValue(obj, dateTime);
                    }
                }
            }

            return obj;
        }

        public static DemgelRedisResult<T> RetreiveObject<T>(string id, IDatabase redisDatabase)
            where T : class, new()
        {
            var ret = RetreiveObject(new T(), id, redisDatabase);
            // Now try to put it all back together
            var result = ret.Object as T;
            var redisResult = new DemgelRedisResult<T>
            {
                Object = result,
                Result = (result == null) ? DemgelResult.NotFound : ret.Result
            };

            return redisResult;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieves an object from redis cache by id
        /// 
        /// usually assumes a key:id structure, but if no key field is supplied
        /// will just search by id
        /// 
        /// can use key:id:suffix
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj"></param>
        /// <param name="id">The id of the object to find</param>
        /// <param name="redisDatabase"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static DemgelRedisResult RetreiveObject(object obj, string id, IDatabase redisDatabase)
        {
            // We need to build the key
            var classAttr = obj.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(true);
            string prefix = null, suffix = null, redisKey;

            foreach (var attr in classAttr)
            {
                if (attr is RedisPrefix)
                {
                    prefix = ((RedisPrefix)attr).Key;
                    Debug.WriteLine("Key Found");
                } else if (attr is RedisSuffix)
                {
                    suffix = ((RedisSuffix) attr).Key;
                    Debug.WriteLine("Suffix Found.");
                }
            }

            if (prefix != null)
            {
                redisKey = suffix != null ? $"{prefix}:{id}:{suffix}" : $"{prefix}:{id}";
            }
            else
            {
                redisKey = suffix != null ? $"{id}:{suffix}" : id;
            }

            Debug.WriteLine($"{redisKey}");

            var ret = redisDatabase.HashGetAll(redisKey);

            var result = new DemgelRedisResult
            {
                Result = DemgelResult.Success
            };

            if (ret.Length == 0)
            {
                result.Result = DemgelResult.NotFound;
                return result;
            }

            // Attempt to set all given properties
            result.Object = ConvertToObject(obj, ret, true);

            var props = result.Object.GetType().GetProperties();

            foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                if (prop.CustomAttributes.Any(x => x.AttributeType == typeof (RedisIdKey)))
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("RedisIdKey was found.");
                    if (!prop.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof (string)))
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("Id can only be of type String");
                    }
                    prop.SetValue(result.Object, id);
                }
                else
                {
                    // If value is not set, then recursion
                    if (prop.GetValue(result.Object) != null) continue;

                    var a = Activator.CreateInstance(prop.PropertyType);
                    var subresult = RetreiveObject(a, id, redisDatabase);
                    if (subresult.IsValid)
                    {
                        prop.SetValue(result.Object, subresult.Object);
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I focus on how `ConvertToRedisHash` is returning its `IEnumerable<HashEntry>`, I get this:

```
public static IEnumerable<HashEntry> ConvertToRedisHash(object o, bool ignoreFail = false)
{
    var hashList = new List<HashEntry>();
    foreach (var prop in o.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        ...
        hashList.Add(new HashEntry(prop.Name, guid.Value.ToString()));
        ...
        hashList.Add(new HashEntry(prop.Name, value));
        ...
    }
    return hashList;
}
```

You're returning an `IEnumerable`, but you're not returning anything until you've collected every item and added them to a `List`. You could instead drop that `List`, and `yield return` the results as they become available:

```
public static IEnumerable<HashEntry> ConvertToRedisHash(object o, bool ignoreFail = false)
{
    foreach (var prop in o.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        ...
        yield return new HashEntry(prop.Name, guid.Value.ToString());
        ...
        yield return new HashEntry(prop.Name, value);
        ...
    }
}
```

---

There's a typo with `RetreiveObject`, should be `RetrieveObject` ;-)

---

I don't like this part:

> ```
> var type = prop.PropertyType;
> if (type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Guid)))
> {
>     Guid value;
>     if (!Guid.TryParse(hashPair, out value))
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             value = new Guid((byte[]) hashPair);
>         }
>         catch
>         {
>             value = Guid.Empty;
>         }
>     }
>     prop.SetValue(obj, value);
> }
> else if (type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(string)))
> {
>     prop.SetValue(obj, (string)hashPair);
> }
> else if (type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(float)))
> {
>     prop.SetValue(obj, (float)Convert.ToDouble(hashPair));
> }
> else if (type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(double)))
> {
>     prop.SetValue(obj, Convert.ToDouble(hashPair));
> }
> else if (type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(int)))
> {
>     prop.SetValue(obj, int.Parse(hashPair));
> }
> else if (type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof (DateTime)))
> {
>     DateTime dateTime;
>     if (DateTime.TryParse(hashPair, out dateTime))
>     {
>         prop.SetValue(obj, dateTime);
>     }
> }
> ```

It seems it would be better off as a `switch` block.